# Form & Upload on One Submit

Tags: php, forms, submit

I've been struggling with this problem all week.

I have a form for capturing data and empty form field validation which prevents the form from being submitted if any of the fields are empty.

Also in the form I have an input which allows a user to upload an image. The problem is users can upload images WITHOUT entering any data in the form. As the image is linked to the form they must be written on a single submit and not independently.

I have only posted a small sample of the code as I think the issue is the form and inputs not the php?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="textandimages.php">

<div><input id="name" class="insetcard" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?PHP print $name ; ?>"/>
<p class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></p></div>

<input type="file" name="upload" />

<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="submitbutton" value="submit">
```

FULL CODE

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
//require("checkLoginSession.php");
$message = $_GET['message'];

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$path = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    //echo '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="" />';

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
}

$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_3 VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($user)."','{$path}')";
if (mysql_query($Query, $Link)) { echo ("Image stored"); }else { die ("Failed to connect to database!: " .mysql_error()); };

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$nameErr = $intelligenceErr = $strengthErr = $speedErr = $energyErr = $fightingErr = $googleErr = $biographyErr = "";
$name = $intelligence = $strength = $speed = $energy = $fighting = $google = $biography = "";

function validate_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $has_errors = false;

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $nameErr = "Enter a name";
    }else{
        $name = validate_input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["intelligence"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $intelligenceErr = "Enter intelligence value";
    } else {
        $intelligence = validate_input($_POST["intelligence"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["strength"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $strengthErr = "Enter strength value";
    } else {
        $strength = validate_input($_POST["strength"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["speed"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $speedErr = "Enter speed value";
    } else {
        $speed = validate_input($_POST["speed"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["energy"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $energyErr = "Enter energy value";
    } else {
        $energy = validate_input($_POST["energy"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["fighting"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $fightingErr = "Enter fighting value";
    } else {
        $fighting = validate_input($_POST["fighting"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["google"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $googleErr = "Enter the googleindex";
    } else {
        $google = validate_input($_POST["google"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["biography"])) {
        $has_errors = true;
        $biographyErr = "Enter a biography";
    } else {
        $biography = validate_input($_POST["biography"]);
    }

    if (!$has_errors)
    {
        $Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
        $user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
        $Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_2 VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($user)."','".mysql_escape_string($name)."','".mysql_escape_string($intelligence)."', '".mysql_escape_string($strength)."', '".mysql_escape_string($speed)."', '".mysql_escape_string($energy)."', '".mysql_escape_string($fighting)."', '".mysql_escape_string($google)."', '".mysql_escape_string($biography)."')";

        if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
            $message = "Card created";
            header("Location: comics.php?message=".urlencode($message));
        } else {

            die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error($Link));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that action="textandimages".php" needs to be changed to action="textandimages.php"

Comment: Daan That's just a typo. The script is named something else.

Comment: You could disable the upload button until the form is entirely filled with javascript.

Comment: @Daan I don't want to use any javascript for this.

Comment: Can you post the PHP code after the form is submitted?

Comment: Add the entire upload part in if(isset($_POST['submit'])) and then check if $_POST['upload'] is empty.

Comment: @Daan I've posted the full code and yes I know it's depreciated! The first part of the code handles the image upload. An image is uploaded into a folder and the path and username (a session for the logged in user) is written into a table.

The second part validates the form and then writes the data into another table against using a session for the logged in users. Both parts work independently. I could have sworn I had this working yesterday but must have made a change somewhere and now it's falling down.

Comment: @Daan I don't understand what you mean by check if $_POST['upload'] is empty? Doesn't my code do that already?

Comment: I could have missed it but where does it stand?

Comment: @Daan I don't follow. The if(isset($_POST['submit'])) is in the form code. Data is being written into two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Test both values in your textandimages.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['upload']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['upload']) ){
// do something
} else { 
//error, something is missing...
}
```